# Android. Repository from data layer with global lifecycle

Tags: android, repository-pattern, kotlin-coroutines, android-mvvm, android-mvp

I have a project that currently supports `MVP` and `MVVM`. Coroutines, hilt, repository pattern are also used.
I need single resources that I will cache.

For example, activity `A` executes a network request, the user can go to activity `B` during the execution of the request. However, I need that, regardless of whether I left activity `A` or not, the network request continues its execution and cache data.

I have a repository that contains the logic for executing a request and caching it. I also tried to provide the repository with the  `@Singleton` annotation using the hilt.

However, as soon as I switch from activity `A` to activity `B`, the network request stops executing and no data is stored in the cache.

I understand that what I have done is not sufficient to make the network request be executed in the background even if I leave the activity, but unfortunately I do not understand how I can implement this.

I also read that it is possible to use the same repository instance in the view models of activity `A` and activity `B`. But what if it is possible to switch from activity `A` to many other activities, then I should use the repository instance in the view models of all activities? In addition, my problem is that one activity can have a view model, and another presenter, because. still not the whole project migrated to `MVVM`.

I tried to find some information on the Internet, but I did not find anything like it.

Please help me. Perhaps someone can share interesting sources with a similar implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Use GlobalScope coroutine to make the request last as long as the Application but you can also use workmanager to make the request and cache it.

For GlobalScope refer to: https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-global-scope/

For WorkManager refer to:
https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager